# Simple filtering in R, but with more than one value

Tags: r

I am well aware of how to extract some data based on a condition, but whenever I try multiple conditions, a struggle ensues.  I have some data and I only want to extract certain years from the df.  Here is an example df:

```
year  value
2006  3
2007  4    
2007  3
2008  5
2008  4
2008  4
2009  5
2009  9
2010  2
2010  8
2011  3
2011  8
2011  7
2012  3
2013  4
2012  6
```

Now let's say I just want 2008, 2009, 2010, and 2011.  I try

```
df<-df[df$year == c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011"),]
```

doesn't work, so then:

```
df<-df[df$year == "2008" & df$year == "2009" 
  & df$year == "2010" & df$year == "2011",]
```

No error messages, just an empty df.  What am I missing?

Comment: you're comparing a numeric column to a character ("2008"..), is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `%in%` and not`==`

```
 df[df$year %in% c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011),]



 year value
4  2008     5
5  2008     4
6  2008     4
7  2009     5
8  2009     9
9  2010     2
10 2010     8
11 2011     3
12 2011     8
13 2011     7
```

Comment: `%in%` someday I will understand you.  Thanks, @Metrics!

Comment: A handy complement to have in your code `%notin% <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y)`

Comment: Went to us that function for the first time today, @Hugh, and got the error message "unexpected SPECIAL in "%notin%".

Comment: Surround the `%notin%` in backticks(`)

Answer (score 1):

As answered `%in%` works but so should using `|`. The `&` is for AND logic, meaning that the year would need to be equal to 2008, 2009, 2010 AND 2011 whereas what you want is the OR operator.

```
df<-df[df$year == "2008" | df$year == "2009" | df$year == "2010" | df$year == "2011",]
```

Comment: Ooooooh!  That is not what I thought `|` meant.  I thought it was just for nesting and that's how I read it in other examples.  Thanks so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as @Metrics answer:

`subset(df, year %in% c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011))`

And if you need help with `%in%`, see `?intersect`

Comment: Thank you, part of my problem is `?%` hasn't worked in the past.

Comment: @Nazer use e.g. backquotes: `?\`%in%\`` (any kind of quote works really here)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `%in%`, try the function `is.element`.  You might find it more intuitive.

`df[is.element(el=df[,"year"], set=c(2008:2011)),]`

Careful, though... switching `el` and `set` gives different results, and it can be confusing which way you want it. For this example, just remember that "set" contains the "subSET" of years that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The questions has been answered but I wanted to add a comment about why your first try gives an unexpected result. This is a good example of R's vector recycling.

I'm guessing you got

```
   year  value
6  2008  4
13 2011  8
```

Why has R done this? What happens is R recycles the vector `c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011")` like the below.

```
year  value compare
2006  3     2008
2007  4     2009
2007  3     2010
2008  5     2011
2008  4     2008
2008  4     2009
2009  5     2010
2009  9     2011
2010  2     2008
2010  8     2009
2011  3     2010
2011  8     2011
2011  7     2008
2012  3     2009
2013  4     2010
2012  6     2011
```

Do you see what's about to happen? When you run

```
df<-df[df$year == c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011"),]
```

it will return the rows where the `year` column and the `compare` column are equal. You didn't get a warning because (by chance) your comparison vector was a divisor of the number of rows, so R thought it was doing the right thing.